# Inequality $\arctan x ≥ x-x^3/3$

Tags: inequality

Can you help me prove $\arctan x ≥ x-x^3/3$? I have thought of taylor but I have not come up with a solution.

Comment: what is $x$ here a real variable?

Comment: this is not true for all real $x$!

Comment: x is a real variable have you found anything?

Comment: arctan(-1) < -1 +1/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let $$f(x)=\arctan(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3}$$ for $x\geq 0$ for $x=0$ we get $f(0)=0$ and for $x>0$ we get $$f'(x)=\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}>0$$ therefore we obtain $$f(x)\geq 0$$ for all real $x$ with $x\geq 0$.

Comment: thanks i thought it would be more difficult because arctan=x-x3/3+x5/5... @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Answer (score 10):

$$
1 - t^4 \le 1
$$
so 
$$
1-t^2 \le \frac1{1+t^2}
$$
now integrate 
$$
\int_0^x (1-t^2)dt \le \int_0^x \frac{dx}{1+t^2}
$$
i.e.
$$
x-\frac{x^3}3 \le \arctan x
$$

Comment: oooo that is the correct one i think

Comment: @user2345215 what do you think?

Comment: @Argyris It's basically the same solution as mine, but written in a trickier way in order to look cool.

Comment: yes i realised it just now because it is from 0 to x thanks you have helped me a lot you know your math

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried derivatives?
$$(\arctan x-x+x^3/3)'=\frac 1{1+x^2}-1+x^2=\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\ge0$$
So the difference is an increasing function. This fact, together the equality when $x=0$ means that
$$\arctan x\ge x-x^3/3\text{ when }x\ge 0\\\arctan x\le x-x^3/3\text{ when }x\le 0$$

Comment: thanks i thought it would be more difficult because arctan=x-x**3/3+x**5/5... @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner